# How to know which drug product is a reference listed drug (RLD)?

Tags: openfda

I trying to figure out how to know which drug product is a reference listed drug (RLD).

Let's take for an example following `spl_set_id`:

[https://api.fda.gov/drug/drugsfda.json?search=products.reference_drug:"Yes"+AND+openfda.spl_set_id:"051be7ae-6504-c2d8-7424-2e328e4fcfc2"](https://api.fda.gov/drug/drugsfda.json?search=products.reference_drug:%22Yes%22+AND+openfda.spl_set_id:%22051be7ae-6504-c2d8-7424-2e328e4fcfc2%22)

I can see that three of six products have `"reference_drug": "Yes"`. This should be a flag that marks drug product as RLD.

**Question:** How can I find related `spl_set_id` for the particular product since in the response I have three of them in the `spl_set_id` array?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I'm Violet with the openFDA team. This one is a bit tricky as it deals with the harmonized data contained in the `openfda` object. The drugs@FDA endpoint contains the field `application_number`, which is what it uses to link to other openFDA endpoints and populate the `openfda` object through the process we label harmonization. To find which `spl_set_id` is linked to each product, you'll need to do some detective work with other endpoints, namely `drug/label` & `drug/ndc` - searching by `spl_set_id`. Alternatively, you can search for the details of those `spl_set_id`s on DailyMed, which already incorporates data from multiple sources into its results.

Sorry I don't have an easier approach for you!